# Stack variable value stuck in threads WINAPI

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

In the following code:
I know the pair object is local to the for loop and is an automatic variable, I pass the reference of this pair to each of my threads.
The problem is inside each thread, the pair value is the same for all threads (the thread function Mat
Add does not modify or write the pair), while if I cout inside the for loop the behavior is correct, why does this happens?

```
for (int i = 0; i < N_THREADS; i++)
{
   pair<int, int> limits(i * dimension / N_THREADS, i * dimension / N_THREADS + 
   dimension / N_THREADS);
   cout << limits.first << \t << limits.second << endl;
   hThreads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, MatAdd, &limits, 0, NULL);
}
```

I verified and in each iteration the reference of the limits pair has the same memory address, but i don't understand why the updated value isn't displayed in forward threads.
I found other solutions but i'm curious about this behavior.

An example with 2 threads (cout inside thread)

Desired

- itr 0: pair.first = 0, pair.second = 5
- itr 1: pair.first = 5, pair.second = 10

Obtained

- itr 0: pair.first = 0, pair.second = 5
- itr 1: pair.first = 0, pair.second = 5

Thank you.

Comment: You're passing the address of `limits`, which goes out of scope on each iteration of your loop.

Comment: `CreateThread(NULL, 0, MatAdd, &limits, 0, NULL);` -- `limits` is a temporary variable and you're passing the address of the temporary.

Comment: As the comments said, your `limits` is a temporary variable in the loop and is released when you leave the loop. You can try to create the pair on the heap, but you also remember to release it.

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT -- It's worse than that - the `limits` is a brand new variable on each iteration of the loop.  The prior versions of `limits` have either disappeared, or maybe worse, the remnants being reused over and over again making the code seem to work properly in some situations, but the same address is being used.